# How to sequentially collapse nodes in force directed graph with multiple parent nodes?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3-force-directed

I'm trying to make force-directed graph nodes collapse, and I'm able to do that from this code below, but this collapses all target nodes, even though the immediate target node has another "edge" to another node, in which case I would like to only be able to collapse the edge i.e. hide the edge and the target node still remains visible, since it also has another parent node still uncollapsed.

In below example, I've "Grandchild" node linked to 2 parent "Child" nodes, now, if I collapse (or click) on any of the child nodes linked to Grandchild, the Grandchild node collapses into the parent along with it's link (edge).

What I'm trying to and need to make it work like it: When I click on Child node, then instead of collapsing the Grand Child into it, I need to check if the child node has any immediate parent and if it is, then I only hide the edge on first child click, and when I click second child parent node, then the Grandchild node along with it's edge collapses into it.

```js
var dataset = {
  "nodes": [{
    "id": 223,
    "type": "Parent",
    "properties": {

    }
  }, {
    "id": 136525,
    "type": "Child",
    "properties": {
      "patient": "6090",
      "batch": "70"
    }
  }, {
    "id": 136448,
    "type": "Child",
    "properties": {
      "patient": "6094",
      "batch": "70"
    }
  }, {
    "id": 136328,
    "type": "Child",
    "properties": {
      "patient": "6082",
      "batch": "70"
    }
  }, {
    "id": 136305,
    "type": "Child",
    "properties": {
      "patient": "6096",
      "batch": "70"
    }
  }, {
    "id": 136303,
    "type": "Child",
    "properties": {
      "patient": "6093",
      "batch": "70"
    }
  }, {
    "id": 136299,
    "type": "Child",
    "properties": {
      "patient": "6091",
      "batch": "70"
    }
  }, {
    "id": 136261,
    "type": "Child",
    "properties": {
      "patient": "6089",
      "batch": "70"
    }
  }, {
    "id": 136212,
    "type": "Child",
    "properties": {
      "patient": "6087",
      "batch": "70"
    }
  }, {
    "id": 136115,
    "type": "Child",
    "properties": {
      "patient": "6078",
      "batch": "70"
    }
  }, {
    "id": 136113,
    "type": "Child",
    "properties": {
      "patient": "6088",
      "batch": "70"
    }
  }, {
    "id": 135843,
    "type": "Child",
    "properties": {
      "patient": "6072",
      "batch": "70"
    }
  }, {
    "id": 555,
    "type": "Grandchild",
    "properties": {

    }
  }],
  "edges": [{
    "id": 0,
    "from": 136113,
    "to": 555,
    "properties": {

    }
  }, {
    "id": 0,
    "from": 136525,
    "to": 555,
    "properties": {

    }
  }, {
    "id": 0,
    "from": 223,
    "to": 136525,
    "properties": {

    }
  }, {
    "id": 0,
    "from": 223,
    "to": 136448,
    "properties": {

    }
  }, {
    "id": 0,
    "from": 223,
    "to": 136328,
    "properties": {

    }
  }, {
    "id": 0,
    "from": 223,
    "to": 136305,
    "properties": {

    }
  }, {
    "id": 0,
    "from": 223,
    "to": 136303,
    "properties": {

    }
  }, {
    "id": 0,
    "from": 223,
    "to": 136299,
    "properties": {

    }
  }, {
    "id": 0,
    "from": 223,
    "to": 136261,
    "properties": {

    }
  }, {
    "id": 0,
    "from": 223,
    "to": 136212,
    "properties": {

    }
  }, {
    "id": 0,
    "from": 223,
    "to": 136115,
    "properties": {

    }
  }, {
    "id": 0,
    "from": 223,
    "to": 136113,
    "properties": {

    }
  }, {
    "id": 0,
    "from": 223,
    "to": 135843,
    "properties": {

    }
  }]
}

var width = 640,
  height = 470;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var force = d3.layout.force()
  .size([width, height])
  //gravity(0.2)
  .linkDistance(height / 6)
  .charge(function(node) {
    if (node.type !== 'ORG') return -2000;
    return -30;
  });

// build the arrow.
svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
  .data(["end"]) // Different link/path types can be defined here
  .enter().append("svg:marker") // This section adds in the arrows
  .attr("id", function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
  .attr("refX", 12)
  .attr("refY", 0)
  .attr("markerWidth", 9)
  .attr("markerHeight", 5)
  .attr("orient", "auto")
  .attr("class", "arrow")
  .append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

var json = dataset;

var edges = [];
json.edges.forEach(function(e) {
  var sourceNode = json.nodes.filter(function(n) {
      return n.id === e.from;
    })[0],
    targetNode = json.nodes.filter(function(n) {
      return n.id === e.to;
    })[0];

  edges.push({
    source: sourceNode,
    target: targetNode,
    value: e.Value
  });
});

for (var i = 0; i < json.nodes.length; i++) {
  json.nodes[i].collapsing = 0;
  json.nodes[i].collapsed = false;
}

var link = svg.selectAll(".link");
var node = svg.selectAll(".node");

force.on("tick", function() {
  // make sure the nodes do not overlap the arrows
  link.attr("d", function(d) {
    // Total difference in x and y from source to target
    diffX = d.target.x - d.source.x;
    diffY = d.target.y - d.source.y;

    // Length of path from center of source node to center of target node
    pathLength = Math.sqrt((diffX * diffX) + (diffY * diffY));

    // x and y distances from center to outside edge of target node
    offsetX = (diffX * d.target.radius) / pathLength;
    offsetY = (diffY * d.target.radius) / pathLength;

    return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "L" + (d.target.x - offsetX) + "," + (d.target.y - offsetY);
  });

  node.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  });
});

update();

function update() {
  var nodes = json.nodes.filter(function(d) {
    return d.collapsing == 0;
  });

  var links = edges.filter(function(d) {
    return d.source.collapsing == 0 && d.target.collapsing == 0;
  });

  force
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .start();

  link = link.data(links)

  link.exit().remove();

  link.enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");

  node = node.data(nodes);

  node.exit().remove();

  node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      return "node " + d.type
    });

  node.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) {
      d.radius = 20;
      return d.radius
    }); // return a radius for path to use 

  node.append("text")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("class", "text")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.type
    });

  // On node hover, examine the links to see if their
  // source or target properties match the hovered node.
  node.on('mouseover', function(d) {
    link.attr('class', function(l) {
      if (d === l.source || d === l.target)
        return "link active";
      else
        return "link inactive";
    });
  });

  // Set the stroke width back to normal when mouse leaves the node.
  node.on('mouseout', function() {
      link.attr('class', "link");
    })
    .on('click', click);

  function click(d) {
    if (!d3.event.defaultPrevented) {
      var inc = d.collapsed ? -1 : 1;
      recurse(d);

      function recurse(sourceNode) {
        //check if link is from this node, and if so, collapse
        edges.forEach(function(l) {
          if (l.source.id === sourceNode.id) {
            l.target.collapsing += inc;
            recurse(l.target);
          }
        });
      }
      d.collapsed = !d.collapsed;
    }
    update();
  }
}
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.node .text {
  fill: white;
  font-size: 8px;
}
.ORG .circle {
  fill: #1d3649;
}
.EMR .circle {
  fill: #B2D0F5;
  stroke: #5596e6;
  stroke-dasharray: 3px, 3px;
  opacity: .5;
}
.EMR .circle:hover {
  fill: #5596e6;
}
.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #eee;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.link.active {
  stroke: #ddd;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
.arrow {
  fill: #666;
}
.arrow.active {
  stroke-width: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<body></body>
```